# How to get accurate calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do a simple calculation in python of multiplying few numbers but I am getting an inaccurate result.

I am trying to solve this
999999999999999999*2*(2-1)/2
from calculation, answer should be 999999999999999999 but I am getting 1000000000000000000

How can I get accurate result ?

```py
a = 999999999999999999*2*(2-1)/2
print(a)
int(a)
```

1e+18

1000000000000000000

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not exact in Python (or really any programming language).  You may try to find a library which offers an exact numeric type.

Comment: use integer division `//` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

```
from decimal import *
a = Decimal('999999999999999999')*2*(2-1)/2
print(a)
```

Output:

```
999999999999999999
```